# I am getting this error from my program "ZeroDivisionError: division by zero". Could someone give me some help on how I could fix it?

Tags: python-3.x

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS2wF.png)

The program consists of generating a table with the aircraft that need maintenance, depending on the maximum hours without maintenance for their class and the accumulated flight hours of each aircraft, with these two values the formula is made:
e = (t - n) / n where,
T: This is the number of hours it has been in operation without being maintained.
N: This is the maximum number of hours of maintenance-free operation for its class.
With this function I try to create a table in which I show several values, one of which is "exceso", just this one gives me that error.

Comment: Please dont post images of the code. Put the code instead. Check that your divident (n in your formula) is not 0

Comment: Also post the full error message **as text**.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the program fails is because you can't divide by zero. One way to solve this problem is to catch if the denominator is 0.

```py
def caso4():
    for i in range(6):
        if (
            horas_vuelo[i] < horas_max[clases_aviones[i]]
            or horas_max[clases_aviones[i]] == 0
        ):
            return

    exceso = (horas_vuelo[i] - horas_max[clases_aviones[i]]) / horas_max[
        clases_aviones[i]
    ]
    if horas_vuelo[i] < horas_max[clases_aviones[i]]:
        print(
            f"{i+1}\t\t{clases_aviones[i]}\t\t{horas_max[clases_aviones[i]]}\t\t{horas_vuelo[i]}\t\t{exceso}"
        )
```